# Password_hash and Password_verify, store password too?

Tags: php

Maybe silly question...,

but i'm asking myself if it's useful to store the password (plain text) in the database once i have hashed it using password_hash() function...

- Since password_verify() only uses hashnSalt to check if pass is correct.
- once the "Villain" obtain access to the db he doesn't have plain text password (will ask him time to bruteforce them)
- If the user forget his password he can't get it back : only way is to recreate a new pass.

i'm on a 50/50..

Comment: it is never ever ever ever ever reasonable to store plaintext passwords.

Comment: Of course you do not store the plaintext passwords, why do you even ask this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do NOT **EVER** under any circumstances store plaintext passwords. Doing this defeats the entire purpose of hashing the password in the first place.

The entire purpose of using a one way hasing algorithm is that if a hacker gets into your site and steals your database it is virtually impossible for that hacker to obtain the passwords for your users without using bruteforce or tables. (The tables risk is also mitigated by the salt introduced by the `password_hash()` function.)

You should never be able to retrieve your users' passwords, even as the site owner/operator (if you can, then a hacker can too). That's why any website that will send you your password instead of having you reset it is a red flag immediately as they are not storing your credentials securely.

The correct way to handle this is if a user forgets their password you send a temporary link which allows the user to create a new password.

Comment: Well thanks for that fast answer, i had a doubt you solved it.

Answer (score 1):

First: never store plain text passwords! Probably the user uses more than one place the same password, and you would give the login information to other services for the attacker.

I would sabe only the created hash and if the user needs to remember the password he/she would have to reset it with a new one. The method to do this you can choose, but sending an email with a unique temporary link the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

if a user forget his password, you can send him/her email with a link to his page and ask him to change his password. or you can set a new password for the user and send it to that user

Comment: What do you mean? How to "send him to his page" without a password?!

Comment: you can create an encrypted link, when user clicks on it, it will redirect the user and set session.

Comment: @Royal Bg And Javid I'm wondering, I gave the almost same answer as guiligan, even with two solutions. why I'm voted down.

Comment: @ Royal Bg, is it really irrelevant?